# Replacing JQuery DOM object with a function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I create a  JQuery object containing HTML returned with the getJSON method, and I would like to call various methods on that JQuery object to retrieve certain DOM elements. The methods I use will be different depending upon the source of the HTML . I have tried building the method chains in advance in an object , var k, and passing that object and the returned DOM object into a function, with the thought that the empty DOM object will be replaced by the DOM object which is a function parameter, that is not happening as var k resolves to an empty string with length=0 in the function. I am fairly new to JS and JQ so I am probably way off on this.

```
var x = $();
var k = {
     "chain1":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(1)').text(),
     "chain2":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(5)').text(),
      "chain3":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(9)').text()}

$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', function(data) {
  x = $(data.contents);
  thisfood.kcal = test(x, k);})

function test(x, k) {
  var product = x.filter('div').find('#top').children('h1').text();
  var y =x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(1)').text();
  var y = k.chain1;
  var kcal_kg = y.match("\\d{1}\\,\\d{3}"); 
  var kcal_serve = y.match("\\s\\d{3}");
  var arr = new Array(kcal_kg, kcal_serve, product);
  return arr;
        }
```

Comment: Did you notice that you have an extra comma at the end of your `k` Object?

Comment: JavaScript does not evaluate like PHP. Notice that `y.match("\\d{1}\\,\\d{3}")` should be `y.match(/\d\,\d{3}/)`.

Answer (score -1):

I really hate Jquery, your code looks as if you are looking forward to publishing your project finalized with Jquery..

Anyhow.. if your looking to replace the jquery selector $("") with a function you should know that the function requires that it returns a DOM element. otherwise an error will be flagged and java script with abort.

Comment: You posted your comment in the wrong area. he is talking about this object var k = {
     "chain1":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(1)').text(),
     "chain2":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(5)').text(),
      "chain3":x.filter('div').find('#feeding').children('p:eq(9)').text(),} which should also end with a ;

Comment: thanks, removed that extra comma - a cut/paste error.

Comment: dont forget your ; on your k object and your json

Comment: was my answer helpful or no? if not please elaborate on your issue you are facing.

Comment: No, punctuation changes did not affect result. The parameter x in the function does not replace the selector x - that's the issue - how do I replace the selector with the function parameter.

Comment: The punctuation will not affect the result, however the ; should be there. Place an alert(data.contents) in the json and tell me if the alert appears.